# Calculating no of non-zero in a column corresponding to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
 d = {'class': [0, 1,1,0,1,0], 'A': [0,4,8,1,0,0],'B':[4,1,0,0,3,1]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

which looks like-

```
    A   B   class
0   0   4   0
1   4   1   1
2   8   0   1
3   1   0   0
4   0   3   1
5   0   1   0
```

I want to calculate for each column the corresponding a,b,c,d which are no of non-zero in column corresponding to class column 1,no of non-zero in column corresponding to class column 0,no of zero in column corresponding to class column 1,no of zero in column corresponding to class column 0

for example-

```
for column A the a,b,c,d are 2,1,1,2
```

explantion- In column A we see that where column[class]=1 the number of non zero values in column A are 2 therefore a=2(indices 1,2).Similarly b=1(indices 3)

My attempt(when the dataframe had equal no of 0 and 1 class)-

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('aaf.csv')

n=len(dataset.columns)  #no of columns

X=dataset.iloc[:,1:n].values

l=len(X) #no or rows


score = []

for i in range(n-1):
    #print(i)

    X_column=X[:,i]
    neg_array,pos_array=np.hsplit(X_column,2)##hardcoded 
    #print(pos_array.size)
    a=np.count_nonzero(pos_array)
    b=np.count_nonzero(neg_array)
    c= l/2-a
    d= l/2-b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
d = {'class': [0, 1,1,0,1,0], 'A': [0,4,8,1,0,0],'B':[4,1,0,0,3,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = (df.set_index('class')
       .ne(0)
       .stack()
       .groupby(level=[0,1])
       .value_counts()
       .unstack(1)
       .sort_index(level=1, ascending=False)
       .T)
print (df)
class     1     0     1     0
      True  True  False False
A         2     1     1     2
B         2     2     1     1

df.columns = list('abcd')
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
A  2  1  1  2
B  2  2  1  1
```

Comment: I want to calculate for each column the values a,b,c,d

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - It count for all columns without `class`, for you it not working?

Comment: It is only calcuating a and b,I wanted to calculate a,b,c,d

Comment: @ubuntu_noob - yes, it count only `A` and `B`, because in sample data are not `c` and `d` columns.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me...I want to calculate for each column the values of the variables a,b,c,d the defintion of which I have mentioned in the question

Comment: The answer for col B in incorrect as the number of non zero related to col['class']=1 is 2

Comment: the answer for colB is 2,2,1,1....is it possible you are interchanging c,d?